# Translation of “hawker” when selling fruits or some other small items in a train

Tags: traduction

I'm trying to find the proper name for someone who sells fruits or some other small items in a train. The seller is walking around the train trying to find customers:

[image]

(image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hawker.jpg; Author Callek6. This file is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 4.0 International license. The picture was taken in the [Yangon Circular Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangon_Circular_Railway).)

What I have found so far:

- *Vendeur*: not very specific.
- *Vendeur de rue*: it's not a street but a train.
- *Colporteur*: I believe it has the connotation of carrying something heavy on one's back, which is not in the case for our train hawker.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the most general and at the same time the most specific term for street, beaches, trains and ships, and eventually planes is "**vendeur ambulant**" or synonymously "**marchand ambulant**". I have never heard of a term used specially for trains.

"**Vendeur**" is not specific, yet it is going to be a common term if not the most common to refer to such a peddler of eatable goods in trains and other places, and as well for other types of goods (papers, gadgets, hats…). "**Marchand**" can also be used; if need be, those terms can be made more specific as to the nature of the goods : marchand de cacahouètes, vendeur de glaces, vendeur de chapeaux de paille, etc.

*Example of use of "vendeur" in a dialog*

— La glace que tu m'a donnée est une glace à la vanille, tu sais que je ne les aime pas.
— Tiens, voilà un euro, le vendeur n'est pas loin, vas acheter celle que tu veux.(*Here you are not likely to use the full term (vendeur ambulant), the abbreviation is usual.*)

*Other examples*

- Le *marchand de glace ambulant* sur la plage ne vient plus dans les après-midi, il faut aller chercher les glaces au restaurant.
- Un *vendeur de bonbons* passait dans l'allée centrale du wagon avec son plateau de sucreries accroché à son cou par une sangle, présentant celui-ci silencieusement et brièvement aux passagers.

"[Colporteur](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=2974718310;)" is not applicable as although a "colporteur" is a "vendeur ambulant", he does his business by  knocking  on doors; I think  in English one calls those **peddlers**". Moreover it is a term that describes an occupation that is not any more that of enough people for its name to have much currency.

(TLFi)  Marchand(e) ambulant(e) qui vend des marchandises à domicile
([internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/colporteur/))  Commerce Ancien — 
Marchand ambulant qui transporte des marchandises et qui les vend en faisant du porte à porte.

Comment: Thanks, I agree, "vendeur/marchand  ambulant" sounds pretty good.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You might anyway want to explain the concept to people you're speaking too. I never met such people in any belgian train for example, so even if you talked about a "vendeur ambulant", some people might not understand what you mean even if the wording is 100% correct.